# node request module: parsing XML as JSON

Tags: json, node.js, xml, node-request

Until recently I've been fetching XML data using the [node request](https://github.com/request/request) module, and then running that XML through an XML to JSON converter.  I discovered by accident that if I set `json: true` as an option (even knowing the endpoint returns XML, not JSON), I was actually getting back JSON:

```
var request = require('request');
var options = { gzip: true, json: true, headers: { 'User-Agent': 'stackoverflow question (https://stackoverflow.com/q/52609246/4070848)' } };
options.uri = 'https://api.met.no/weatherapi/locationforecast/1.9/?lat=40.597&lon=-74.26';
request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    console.log(`body for ${options.uri}: ${JSON.stringify(body)}`);
});
```

The above call returns JSON, whereas the [raw URL](https://api.met.no/weatherapi/locationforecast/1.9/?lat=40.597&lon=-74.26) is actually sending XML.  Sure enough, with `json: false` the returned data is XML:

```
var request = require('request');
var options = { gzip: true, json: true, headers: { 'User-Agent': 'stackoverflow question (https://stackoverflow.com/q/52609246/4070848)' } };
options.uri = 'https://api.met.no/weatherapi/locationforecast/1.9/?lat=40.597&lon=-74.26';
options.json = false; // <<--- the only difference in the request
request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    console.log(`body for ${options.uri}: ${body}`);
});
```

So I thought "that's handy", until I tried the same trick with a [different URL that also returns XML](https://graphical.weather.gov/xml/SOAP_server/ndfdXMLclient.php?whichClient=NDFDgen&lat=40.597&lon=-74.26&product=time-series&temp=tempSubmit=Submit), and in this case the returned data is still XML despite using the same request options:

```
var request = require('request');
var options = { gzip: true, json: true, headers: { 'User-Agent': 'stackoverflow question (https://stackoverflow.com/q/52609246/4070848)' } };
options.uri = 'https://graphical.weather.gov/xml/SOAP_server/ndfdXMLclient.php?whichClient=NDFDgen&lat=40.597&lon=-74.26&product=time-series&temp=tempSubmit=Submit';
request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    console.log(`body for ${options.uri}: ${body}`);
});
```

What is the difference here?  How do I get the latter request to return the data in JSON format (so that I can avoid the step of converting XML to JSON myself)?  Maybe the endpoint in the first example can detect that JSON is requested and it does in fact return JSON rather than XML?

**EDIT** weirdly, the first request is now returning XML rather than JSON even with `json: true`.  So maybe this behaviour was down to what was being sent from the endpoint, and they've changed this even since I posted a few hours ago

Comment: They're watching you!  :)

Comment: It's definitely possible, since I deliberately added a link to this post in the user-agent :)

Comment: Well, if you're still watching this post `met.no` devs, change it back!  It's pretty standard stuff in the REST API world to offer multiple representations of your resource and differentiate on Accept and Content-Type headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So now that the behavior is unrepeatable, the answer is less useful for your particular problem, but I think it's worth pointing out that when you set `json:true` on the `request` module, it does a few things under the hood for you:

- Sets the Accept header to 'application/json'
- Parses the response body using `JSON.parse()`
- Request types with a body also get the body automatically serialized as JSON
- Request types with a body also get the Content-Type header added as 'application/json'

So perhaps they did change it, but there are plenty of web services I've seen that will detect the content-type to send based on the Accept header and respond appropriately for some set of types that make sense (usually XML or JSON, but sometimes CSV, TXT, HTML, etc).

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful, and interesting to note that (as I suspected as being a possibility) the endpoint can tailor its response based on the request (e.g. returning JSON instead of XML).  At least I can rule out the possibility that the `request` module itself is receiving XML and converting it to JSON internally (based on `json: true`)... so it is safest for now to request XML (`json: false`) and do the converting myself.

Answer (score 0):

To handle XML query, I usually do something like this using the request module:

```
import parser from "xml2json";
const resp = await rp({
  method: "POST",
  url: 'some url',
  form: {xml_query}, // set XML query to xml_query field
});
const parsedData = parser.toJson(resp, {
  object: true, // returns a Javascript object instead of a JSON string
  coerce: true, // makes type coercion.
});
```